# Is it safe to move data between threads using a lock less queue of pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have implemented a simple circular buffer to move data between threads using ([Camerons excellent](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++)) `readerwriterqueue` to prevent (de)allocations in my application. The code looks something like this:

```
using ElemPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>;
moodycamel::ReaderWriterQueue<ElemPtr> emptyQueue(10);
moodycamel::ReaderWriterQueue<ElemPtr> dataQueue(10);
LoadQueueWithPointers(emptyQueue);

//If statements removed for brevity
auto producer = [&]() {
    ElemPtr ptr;
    while (true) {
        emptyQueue.try_dequeue(ptr);
        LoadData(ptr);
        dataQueue.try_enqueue(std::move(ptr));
    }
};

//If statements removed for brevity
auto consumer = [&]() {
    ElemPtr ptr;
    while (true) {
        dataQueue.try_dequeue(ptr);
        ProcessData(ptr);
        emptyQueue.try_enqueue(std::move(ptr));
    }
};

std::thread producerThread(producer);
std::thread consumerThread(consumer);
```

When examining this code, it would seem to me that corruption of data is possible if the consumer thread receives the pointer before the data (which the pointer references) has been update in RAM. I have tried to induce data corruption using delays, different queue lengths, different data sizes and by moving the threads to physically separate processors (sockets). So far I have seen no data corruption issues.

Thus my question is: have I so far been lucky and there is a data corruption problem that is waiting to happen **OR** do the memory fences (`std::memory_order_acquire`, `std::memory_order_release`) used by `moodycamel::ReaderWriterQueue` also protect my (non-atomic) memory operations?

Comment: Memory order of atomic load/stores is there because they control how other non-atomic load/stores can be reordered. So, supposedly, you're fine. Note, however, that if you test this on a strongly ordered CPU (like x86), then a lot of potential issues get hidden by the CPU. So it is possible, that on a different CPU with weaker guarantees (like ARM), you'll have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: As long as the implementation of `ReaderWriterQueue<>` uses atomic types with the correct memory orderings, you are fine.

The memory orderings that you need are `memory_order_release` on the writer side, and `memory_order_acquire` on the reader side. These memory orders imply, that all writes before an atomic write need to happen first, and that all reads after an atomic read need to happen later. These other writes/reads include your accesses to the data behind your `ElemPtr`s.

Since the queue itself needs to send data from one thread to the other, it needs to use the exact same memory orderings on its own atomic metadata to be able to send your payload data pointers. As such, you should be safe if the `ReaderWriterQueue<>` is implemented correctly.